# Method for get the total utilization Mips of All Vms in cloudsim?

Tags: java, cloud, cpu-usage, cloudsim

In CloudSim, how to assign the RAM and CPU usage of all cloudlets ?
How to get the total utilization of ram and Mips for all VM(s)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a method of class Vm

```
    getTotalUtilizationOfCpuMips(double time)
```

Get utilization created by all cloudlets running on this VM in MIPS.
You can calculate total utilization of particular VM and so you can find total utilization Mips of all. Same is documented [here](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/doc/api/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Vm.html) 
You can also refer [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloudsim/aKYKKu1lozA)